# how To select fields from two tables

Tags: sql

I need to select these fields-----

```
user_id,
sales_vertical,
partner_id,
category,
sub_category,
stage_id,
exp_revenue,
action,
action_date,
title_action,
date_action,
details from opportunity_history table
```

and

```
tri_title,
tri_subtitle 
from res_partner table 
where res_partner.partner_id = opportunity_history.partner_id
```

in a single query.
how can we do that?

Thanks Adil

Comment: Can you try to format your question better and give a bit more background. The question's current state makes it hard for us to see what you want to do really.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple SQL Select from 2 Tables (What is a Join?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040587/simple-sql-select-from-2-tables-what-is-a-join)

Answer (score 14):

Why so many downvotes and no comments?

Try with:

```
SELECT 
    oh.ser_id,
    oh.sales_vertical,
    oh.partner_id,
    oh.category,
    oh.sub_category,
    oh.stage_id,
    oh.exp_revenue,
    oh.action,
    oh.action_date,
    oh.title_action,
    oh.date_action,
    oh.details,

    rp.tri_title,
    rp.tri_subtitle

FROM opportunity_history AS oh
  INNER JOIN res_partner AS rp
    ON rp.partner_id = oh.partner_id
```

Comment: So many downvotes and no comments because it's obvious that someone hasn't even tried to figure out the answer.  Joins would be like day 2 in some "SQL in 7 days" book.  (Just checked...they're "day 6" in the 21 days book.  [Literally.](http://web.ing.puc.cl/~jlortiz/Teach_Yourself_SQL_in_21_days_FULL.pdf))

Comment: but then, they should tell him that too - I don't like lazy people either, but I think that they might be helped to get corrected :)

Answer (score 3):

```
select user_id, sales_vertical, partner_id, category, sub_category, stage_id, exp_revenue, action, action_date,title_action,date_action,details, tri_title, tri_subtitle 

from opportunity_history, res_partner

where res_partner.partner_id =opportunity_history.partner_id
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution (not in single query)

`(SELECT user_id, sales_vertical, partner_id, category,
         sub_category, stage_id, exp_revenue, action_date, 
         title_action, date_action, details
  FROM opportunity_history)
UNION ALL
(SELECT tri_title, tri_subtitle FROM res_partner
WHERE res_partner.partner_id=opportunity_history.partner_id)`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.sales_vertical, a.partner_id, a.category, a.sub_category, 
a.stage_id, a.exp_revenue, a.action, a.action_date, a.title_action, a.date_action, 
a.details, b.tri_title, b.tri_subtitle FROM opportunity_history a, res_partner b 
WHERE b.partner_id =a.partner_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Check these:
- [SELECT Data from multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055770/select-data-from-multiple-tables) (for any number of tables, not just 2)
- [SQL select statement from 2 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776278/sql-select-statement-from-2-tables)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT        TOP (100) PRJ.tblAvoidance.Av_ID, PRJ.tblAvoidance.Project_ID, PRJ.tblNDCProjects.Title, PRJ.tblAvoidance.Activity_Year, PRJ.tblAvoidance.CO2, PRJ.tblAvoidance.CH4, PRJ.tblAvoidance.N2O, 
                         PRJ.tblAvoidance.Updated_By, PRJ.tblAvoidance.Updated_On
FROM            PRJ.tblAvoidance INNER JOIN
                         PRJ.tblNDCProjects ON PRJ.tblAvoidance.Project_ID = PRJ.tblNDCProjects.ID

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please elaborate your answer adding some description of what it does and why is it better than other answers here. Also, please consult this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for formatting help.