# SQL SELECT * FROM 2 tables

Tags: sql, select

I am building a small database app for friends where table 1 is contacts and table 2 is users. I can find email on both (One as the loggued in user and the other as the owner of the contact)

```
SELECT *
  FROM contacts
 WHERE contacts.username = users.email
```

I try to show all contacts fields where username is equal to already loggued in users (email)

Thanks you very much!

Comment: Please tell us what is stopping you from showing all contacts fields where username is equal to already loggued in users (email)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT Data from multiple tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055770/select-data-from-multiple-tables)

Comment: So...what's the question???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to `JOIN` two tables together. Ideally, you don't want to use the email as the primary key on a table (the smaller the data, the faster your `JOIN` will be); a better option would be to add an auto-incrementing Id (integer) to both the Contacts and Users tables, set as the primary key (unique identifier). Joining on integers is much faster, as integers are 4 bytes per row, vs string which (in MySQL) is 1 per character length (latin1 encoding) + 1 byte.

Anyway, back to the original question. I believe the query you're looking for (MySQL syntax) is:

```
SELECT c.Id, c.Col1, u.Col2, ...
FROM contacts AS c
INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.email = c.username
```

Additionally, I would avoid the use of `*`, as it slows down the query a bit. Instead, try to specify the exact columns you need.

Comment: Hi Chosun, I have read a lot about the subject since. Thanks for all of those tips! About the MySQL, it's still showing all the table (Not showing only those rows that matches u.email = c.username) I've checked syntax, database exact name etc... nothing to do :( I'll keep searching on the subject

Comment: Hi @MAC, it's going to show all the columns because I'm using *. If you want to return only certain columns, do the following: SELECT c.Id, c.Name, u.Name...

Comment: I updated my response to reflect that. Also, if you find this answer to answer your question, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Also, I would suggest you learn about joins in SQL.

```
SELECT *
  FROM contacts
INNER JOIN
  users on contacts.username = users.email
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Inner Join:

```
SELECT *
  FROM contacts as c
INNER JOIN
  users as u on u.email = c.username
```